# Displaying video on a monitor without a graphic interface

Tags: terminal, video, display, yocto

I am working on a microcomputer with Yocto operating system (based on openembedded) where I don't have any graphical environment. The system is quite heavily loaded, and I would like to avoid adding a GUI to it. Recently there has been a need to project video from cameras, connected to the microcomputer (RTSP), to a screen, via HDMI.

Assuming I can install any application on the device, do you know of any solution that would allow me to display the image on the screen? Currently, after connecting the HDMI cable, all I see is the system terminal.

Comment: Have a look at the framebuffer device `/dev/fbX`, and tools for it.

Comment: Yes, that was what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @dirkt I finally did it using `ffmpeg` with command like

```
ffmpeg -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 1000000 -i <RTSP_stream_addr> -pix_fmt bgra -loglevel quiet -f fbdev /dev/fb0
```

Comment: How demanding is this of the system?

Comment: According to htop it uses ~5% of CPU on my Jetson Nano